# Feature comparison: V8 vs. iOS JavaScriptCore

Tags: android, ios, v8, javascriptcore

Without using any non-deafult switches (i.e. no --harmony), are there language features, global properties, etc. that exist in V8 ([at 69a0664](https://github.com/v8/v8/commit/69a0664da1dc06467698cc45c06877224a7cf616)) but not in JSC ([at f27bfeb](https://github.com/wcwynn/JavaScriptCore-iOS/commit/f27bfeb56d33aa09f8097ebfb196354971f7b88f)) and *vice versa*?

I'm doing Android/iOS work and want to make sure the same scripts will work on both.

Comment: Can you clarify? If you stick to the core language instead of extensions (like `Math.imul`) then there should be no problem at all.

Comment: What are the extensions? If they both implement one, I'm fine with allowing it - but I can't find any definitive listing and there's no way to recursively enumerate every property in the global scope.

Comment: They are extensions if you cannot find them in http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/

Comment: But what are they? I need a list of the extensions that V8 and JSC implement.

Comment: well I only know stuff like `print`, `Math.imul` and so on, I don't have any list sorry

Comment: And are their ECMAScript implementations both complete and equivalent?

Comment: No, you can see that from here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecmascript#Conformance_tests

Comment: @OrangeDog, I don't think you'll find a comprehensive list anywhere. In any case, I'd strongly advise against using anything outside the standard. We have standards for a reason, and most extra cruft in browsers is just historic garbage and backwards compatibility hacks anyway.

Comment: A community wiki answer is acceptible. The problem is, I can't block things unless I know what they are. The conformance tests thing looks like a good place to start, but it doesn't actually say which tests it failed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of ECMAScript 5 features, going by [this table](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/), both have attempted to implement everything.

test262 failures for Mobile Safari (iOS 6.1.3):

- **10.4.2_1.1** eval within global execution context
- **10.4.2_1.2** eval within global execution context
- **15.5.4.9_3** Tests that String.prototype.localeCompare treats a missing "that" argument, undefined and "undefined" as equivalent
- **15.5.4.9_CE** Tests that String.prototype.localeCompare returns 0 when comparing Strings that are considered canonically equivalent by the Unicode standard.
- **15.9.3.1_5** multi-argument Date construction

test262 failures for Chrome 28:

- **11.2.3-3_3** Call arguments are not evaluated before the check is made to see if the object is actually callable (undefined member)
- **15.5.4.9_6** Checking String.prototype.localeCompare.prototype
- **15.5.4.9_7** Checking if creating the String.prototype.localeCompare object fails
- **15.8.2.8_6** Checking if Math.exp is approximately equals to its mathematical values on the set of 64 argument values; all the sample values is calculated with LibC
- **15.9.3.1_5** multi-argument Date construction

Caveat: these aren't necessarily the corresponding versions, but are just what I have to hand.